# AngularJS / Restful Smart Caching

Tags: angularjs, rest, caching, single-page-application, restangular

I'm looking for a solution for "smart" caching in a restful SPA (I'm using AngularJS). For example, if the app wants a list of widgets (e.g., `/widgets`), then later the application wants a specific widget (e.g., `/widgets/<widgetId>`), I want the app to simply do a find on the response from the first request rather than making a second request to the resource.

This would save a request when a user lands on a listing view, then navigates to a single item view. However, if the user initially lands on the single item view, the app would know it still needed to fetch `/widgets/<widgetId>` as `/widgets` was never called.

I looked through $resource and $http, but didn't see anything specifically related to this sort of behavior. It looks like I might be able to use hooks in Restangular, but it's not something that's supported out of the box.

Thanks!

Comment: ng-active-resource supports caching: https://github.com/FacultyCreative/ngActiveResource

Comment: @Manube thanks! it looks like that project stalled, but it led me to js-data, which looks promising.

Comment: you are right, it does look promising!